# Does a Ridable Construct Exist?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, mounted-combat, mount

I am looking for a creature of the type [Construct](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#constructType) that is explicitly capable of being *ridden*. A construct that is big and strong enough to carry another creature is not sufficient, I want something that is clearly suitable as a mount, the way a horse or griffon is.

Does such a creature exist, and if so, where?

The only candidates I have found (and rejected) are:

- The Warforged Charger from Monster Manual 3, which is a quadruped, but has no rules for being ridden.
- Various Figurines of Wondrous Power, which create real living creatures, even if they look weird and are statues most of the time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Riding Constructs

These constructs list details indicating they are supposed to be ridden.

- The **brass steed** (*Heroes of Battle* 153-4) is in a section entitled Battlefield Steeds, and its description includes its carrying capacity as do many mounts.
- The **clockwork pony** and **clockwork stallion** (*Monster Manual 4* 32-3) each have the special ability rider response, making them easier to use as mounts.
- The **equine golem** (*Arms and Equipment Guide* 87-8) has as part of its description information about the negative impact of riding the creature for long stretches.

Further, either of the following templates when applied to a creature give that creature the type construct.

- Apply the template **effigy** (*Complete Arcane* 151-3) to any corporeal aberration, animal, dragon, giant, humanoid, magical beast, monstrous humanoid, or vermin also capable of explicitly being used as a mount.
- Apply the template **elder eidolon** (*Lords of Madness* 149-8) to any aberration, animal, dragon, giant, humanoid, magical beast, monstrous humanoid, plant, or vermin also capable of explicitly being used as a mount.

Comment: +1 but u might want to annotate that the "Arms & Equipment Guide" is 3.0 since some people don't allow 3.0 with 3.5 even though they are very close

Comment: @Ben-Jamin: That's a moderately common houserule, I guess, but 3.0 material that hasn't been obsoleted by 3.5 material is still explicitly valid by RAW, so there's that.

Comment: Oh, I use it & a bit of other 3.0 materialjust saying I thought it would be a helpful notation.