# Counting as mounted without a mount?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation

I've built a ranger for a game recently, and am stuck on my choice of combat style feat. There's an option to get Ride-By Attack as a bonus feat (sans prerequisites, because it's from ranger), and I was thinking that it'd be incredibly cool to have a pseudo-Spring Attack that works with charges.

So with that in mind, is there a way in D&D 3.5 to count oneself as mounted without actually *being* mounted? I've looked but couldn't find one, so I'm hoping the combined wisdom of this site might know of a way.

Ideally, this would be something available to a LA +0 race (through feats, class levels, items, or the like), but it's not strictly necessary.

Comment: Wielding a battle stepladder maybe?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to actually be mounted? E.g. a small ranger riding a dog could work fine for most situations.

Comment: @fectin Off the top of my head I can think of many reasons not to want to be mounted, but ultimately it really *does not matter* for the purposes of answering this question.

Comment: @KRyan it matters in that it looked a lot like an X-Y problem.

Comment: It really isn't. If I were looking to play a mounted character I would have said so. The question is about exploiting a ranger's no-prerequisites-needed bonus feat to get a charge-enabled Spring Attack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No official feats allow a creature to be counted as mounted when the creature's *not* actually mounted, and no class features, mundane or magical items, or special abilities that I'm aware of have such an effect either.

However, the [centaur](http://dndsrd.net/monstersBtoC.html#centaur) on Combat says, "A centaur employing a lance deals double damage when it charges, just as a rider on a mount does" (*Monster Manual* 32). *Savage Species* on page 109 expands on this, saying, "Even centaur characters benefit from" the feats [Mounted Archery](http://dndsrd.net/featsList.html#mounted-archery) (*Player's Handbook* 98), [Ride-By Attack](http://dndsrd.net/featsAll.html#ride-by-attack) (*PH* 99), [Spirited Charge](http://dndsrd.net/featsAll.html#spirited-charge) (*PH* 100), and [Trample](http://dndsrd.net/featsAll.html#trample) (*PH* 101-2) (but not, apparently, the feat [Mounted Combat](http://dndsrd.net/featsAll.html#mounted-combat) (*PH* 98), sadly). And *Races of Faerûn* piles on, saying that "centaurs can acquire the Spirited Charge and Trample feats (ignoring the prerequisites) and apply the benefits to their own melee attacks" (132).

Taken as whole, it's reasonable for the DM to make a house rule saying that a centaur *both* counts as mounted *and* doesn't need the feat Mounted Combat to meet a feat's prerequisites (much like because of "its centaurlike construction, a [zelekhut](http://dndsrd.net/monstersHtoI.html#zelekhut-inevitable) qualifies for feats as if it had the Mounted Combat feat" (*MM* 160)).

Then it's just a matter of assuming the form of a centaur. The path of least resistance for the typical ranger is likely a *wand of wild runner* [trans] (*Spell Compendium* 239) (4th-level spell at caster level 7) (420 gp/charge; 0 lbs.), although the 2nd-level Sor/Wiz spell [*alter self*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsAtoB.html#alter-self) [trans] (*Player's Handbook* 197) when employed by, for example, a lupin (*Dragon Compendium Volume 1* 18-21) would also work as both centaur and lupin share the type monstrous humanoid.

You may also want to ask the DM if *other* creatures with similar body types—like the bariaur (*Planar Handbook* 7-8), dracotaur (*Monster Manual III* 42-3), hybsil (*Monstrous Compendium: Monsters of Faerûn* 61), and wemic (*Races of Faerûn* 149-51)—benefit like a centaur from *their* tauric forms. (Those are—if you're curious—ram, semidragon, antelope, and lion, respectively.)

(Also, instead of an actual, living or undead mount, consider something requiring less upkeep or less necromancy like [a construct that can be ridden](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/56294/8610); a magic item like maybe the [*broom of flying*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#broom-of-flying) (*Dungeon Master's Guide* 250-1) (17,000 gp; 3 lbs.) or the [*figurine of wondrous power* (golden lions)](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#figurines-of-wondrous-power-golden-lions) (*DMG* 256) (16,500 gp; 0 lbs.); or even a spell like the 1st-level Sor/Wiz spell [*mount*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsMtoO.html#mount) [conj] (*PH* 256) (*caution:* it's not war-trained!), the 3rd-level Sor/Wiz spell [*phantom steed*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsPtoR.html#phantom-steed) [conj] (*PH* 260-1) or the 3rd-level Drd and 3rd-level Rgr spell *bottle of smoke* [conj] (*SpC* 27-8).)

Comment: Consider adding the Bariaur (*Planar Handbook* p7) which is medium, and LA +1, 0RHD. It only shares the centaur's shape, not the lancing bonus though, so the DM would need convincing that the *unlabeled* text in the centaur's entry is a feature of the centaur's shape, and not of only centaurs. Actually *Savage Species* p109 says "Even centaurs benefit from [spirited charge, et. al.]..."

Comment: Also note the [zelekhut](http://dndsrd.net/monstersHtoI.html#zelekhut-inevitable "dndsrd.net zelekhut inevitable") entry (centaur-shape counts as Mounted Combat feat), and there's info in *Races of Faerûn* (p132) re: Spirited charge and Trample being available to centaurs. And the BoED Bariaur is higher HD and LA than the one from PlH. That book calls the BoED Bariaur 'Exalted Bariaur'

Comment: @Chemus I always liked the *Planar Handbook* reference to the *Book of Exalted Deeds* bariaur, just for being about the closest any WotC book gets to throwing shade at another (and the authors of *BoED* deserve it).

Comment: @Chemus This answer would be less than half of what it is without your help. Thank you.

Comment: My pleasure. I had considered making my own answer early on, but it wasn't necessary; you had the right answer. I just wanted to reinforce it.